# get 3 peole have higher value from sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image: table name: dataclass]

i have a table look like at the top.
i want to show the 3 students that have higher value,
i have tried command

```
$higher= mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * from dataclass ORDER BY score ASC LIMIT 3");
```

but the result is only show 3 with random score,

could you help me?

Comment: please tag appropriate database

Comment: How about if you have same name?

Comment: db schema is what?

Comment: are you not paying attention to comments up here? or just answers?

Comment: *"Thank you Jan Vorisek your solution is work :) – Z Channel"* - and thank you for ignoring this section. Next time we ask for clarification; you'll wait more time if nobody gives you answers.

Comment: voted to close as a typo because that's just what this was all along; a typo. Incorrect column type

Comment: and also thank for you all to try solve my case :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to sort the results from highest to lowest, but you are doing the opposite as for now.

Change your code to:

```
$higher= mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * from dataclass ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3");
```

Note that DESC means you are sorting from highest to lowest. Also make sure you column "score" is of a type INT, FLOAT or DOUBLE!

Comment: i already tried your code, the result only show 3 people with random score

Comment: Check the type of your score column! It won't work if it is VARCHAR....

Comment: yes you are right the type of score is varchar,
what should i do?

Comment: Change it to INT or FLOAT :)

Answer (score 4):

Use Desc

```
SELECT * from dataclass ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 1):

this one if you have a data with same name and you need it dictincly with no duplicate.

```
select * from dataclass  group by name ORDER BY score desc limit 3
```